# PasswordHasher gives different hash result after dotnet 7 update

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

We have updated our ASP.NET Core 6 application to dotnet 7 and password hashing gives different results as before.
Our configuration with dotnet 6 was:

```
private static readonly IPasswordHasher<object> s_passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<object>(Options.Create(new PasswordHasherOptions
        {
            CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV3,
            IterationCount = 10000
        }));
```

Dotnet 7 update went through with minor problems, nothing that could cause this. I've already checked breaking changes but nothing found there either.

We try to check the password with the VerifyHashedPassword method like this and it always gives "Failed".

```
    result.Status =
        user.Password != null && PasswordHelper.VerifyHashedPassword(user.Password, query.Password) == PasswordVerificationResult.Success ?
        AuthenticateUserStatus.Successful :
        AuthenticateUserStatus.Failed;
```

How can I get back the hashing algorithm used by dotnet6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the .net 7 and .net 6 is .net 7 add the codes which  requires SHA512 now, if you want to use .net 6 passwrod hasher, please modify your codes to use the old one instead of the new one, or modify your codes to use SHA512 encrypt the password.

Details, you could refer to below codes:

.Net 7:

```
        case 0x01:
            if (VerifyHashedPasswordV3(decodedHashedPassword, providedPassword, out int embeddedIterCount, out KeyDerivationPrf prf))
            {
                // If this hasher was configured with a higher iteration count, change the entry now.
                if (embeddedIterCount < _iterCount)
                {
                    return PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded;
                }

                // V3 now requires SHA512. If the old PRF is SHA1 or SHA256, upgrade to SHA512 and rehash.
                if (prf == KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1 || prf == KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256)
                {
                    return PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded;
                }

                return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
            }
```

.Net 6:

```
            case 0x01:
                int embeddedIterCount;
                if (VerifyHashedPasswordV3(decodedHashedPassword, providedPassword, out embeddedIterCount))
                {
                    // If this hasher was configured with a higher iteration count, change the entry now.
                    return (embeddedIterCount < _iterCount)
                        ? PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded
                        : PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
                }
```